# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (3,) for Tensor 'X:0', which has shape '(1, 3)'

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to do a multivariate linear regression and I am having some issues. Namely, I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (3,) for Tensor 'X:0', which has shape '(1, 3)'
```

I have 3 feature variables, which I call trainX and 1 label, which I call trainY. Their shapes are the following (they are numpy arrays):

```
trainX.shape:
(2500, 3)
trainY.shape:
(2500,)
```

The following piece of code defines the tensors that I use to compute the model:

```
X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder("float", [1, 3], name="X")
Y = tf.compat.v1.placeholder("float", [1], name="Y")

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3, 1]), name="W")
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]), name="b")
```

I calculate the predicted label and the cost function and the optimizer by doing:

```
predicted_y = tf.matmul(X, W) + b
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(predicted_y-Y, 2)) / (2 * n)
optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

I am getting the error in the tensor-flow session, namely in the following piece of code:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        for (_x, _y) in zip(trainX, trainY):
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: _x, Y: _y})
        if (epoch + 1) % 100 == 0:
            c = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: trainX, Y: trainY})
            print("Epoch", (epoch + 1), ": cost =", c, "W =", sess.run(W), "b =", sess.run(b))
    # Storing necessary values to be used outside the Session
    training_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: trainX, Y: trainY})
    weight = sess.run(W)
    bias = sess.run(b)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`trainX` has shape `(2500, 3)`, so when you iterate over `trainX` you get values with shape `(3,)`.  To match the shape of your placeholder "X", you need them to have shape `(1, 3)`.  This can be accomplished with [`numpy.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```py
# do this after loading trainX
trainX = trainX.reshape((-1, 1, 3))
# new shape: (2500, 1, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting! I now get the following error: "ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape () for Tensor 'Y:0', which has shape '(1,)'"

Comment: I fixed it by reshaping trainY (-1, 1, 1) and by adding "None, 1" in Y. Thank you!

Comment: Oops, sorry I didn't catch that one.  Try a similar reshape for trainY: `trainY = trainY.reshape(-1, 1)`

Comment: sorry but it doesn't actually work. I get the following error "ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (2500, 1, 3) for Tensor 'X:0', which has shape '(1, 3)'". I get that error when "c = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: trainX, Y: trainY})" runs... Any suggestions?

Comment: Your graph is configured to accept one example at a time, so when you pass in the entire array `trainX` and `trainY`, you get the error.  I think you need to loop through the training examples and compute the cost for each one, then take the average cost outside of the loop.  Does that make sense?